# Add a user into a new table after signing in (submit table) with new information from the client

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

At first a person sign-in to the site. Secondly they should decide a kind of users **(freelancer / employer)**. In this stage they should fill a form . We produce some codes to insert this user to database by this form but it does not work properly.

I use session to keep **userId** but after executing the code the other **userId** will insert to the table.

```
<?php
include "../../inc/inc.php";
$frame->RequestMethodPost();


if (


    isset($_POST['selected'])
    &&
    isset($_POST['workexperience'])
    &&
    isset($_POST['profileimg'])
    &&
    isset($_POST['backgroundimg'])
    &&
    isset($_POST['shortdescription'])
    &&
    isset($_POST['description'])
    &&
    isset($_POST['language'])
    &&
    isset($_POST['timefee'])
    &&
    isset($_POST['hours'])
    &&
    isset($_POST['projecttype'])
    &&
    isset($_POST['available'])
    &&
    isset($_POST['mobile'])
    &&
    isset($_POST['profileimgname'])
    &&
    isset($_POST['backgroundimgname'])
    &&


    !empty($_POST['selected'])
    &&
    !empty($_POST['workexperience'])
    &&

    !empty($_POST['shortdescription'])
    &&
    !empty($_POST['description'])
    &&
    !empty($_POST['language'])
    &&
    !empty($_POST['timefee'])
    &&
    !empty($_POST['hours'])
    &&
    !empty($_POST['projecttype'])
    &&
    !empty($_POST['available'])
    &&
    !empty($_POST['mobile'])



){



    $subcatId = $db->Real(($_POST['selected']));
    $subcatId1[] = (explode(",",$subcatId));


    $workexperience = $db->Real(($_POST['workexperience']));
    $profileimg= $db->Real(($_POST['profileimg']));
    $backgroundimg = $db->Real(($_POST['backgroundimg']));
    $description = $db->Real(($_POST['description']));
    $shortdescription = $db->Real(($_POST['shortdescription']));
    $language = $db->Real(($_POST['language']));
    $timefee = $db->Real(($_POST['timefee']));
    $hours = $db->Real(($_POST['hours']));
    $projecttype = $db->Real(($_POST['projecttype']));
    $available = $db->Real(($_POST['available']));
    $mobile = $db->Real(($_POST['mobile']));
    $profileimgname = $db->Real(($_POST['profileimgname']));
    $backgroundimgname = $db->Real(($_POST['backgroundimgname']));
    session_start();
    if( isset($_SESSION["login"]) && $_SESSION["login"]==true ) {
        $freelancerid= $_SESSION["submitid"];
        $select = mysqli_query($db->connect(),"SELECT * from submit where id=$freelancerid");
        $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($select);
        $name=$result['name'];
        $family=$result['family'];
        $email=$result['email'];
        $username=$result['username'];
        $password=$result['password'];


        $insertfree = mysqli_query($db->connect(), "INSERT INTO freelancer (id, name, family, email, password, shortdescription, description, reg_date, reg_time, username, timefee, projecttype, available, mobile, workexperience, language, hours)
                                                                     value ('$freelancerid','$name','$family','$email','$password','$shortdescription','$description','','','$username','$timefee','$projecttype','$available','$mobile','$workexperience','$language','$hours')");
        $insertimgprofile=  mysqli_query($db->connect(),"INSERT INTO gallery(id, img_address, freelancer_id, employer_id, freeco_id, empco_id) value ('','$profileimgname','$freelancerid','','','')");
        $insertimgbackground=  mysqli_query($db->connect(),"INSERT INTO gallery(id, img_address, freelancer_id, employer_id, freeco_id, empco_id) value ('','$backgroundimgname','$freelancerid','','','')");

        foreach($subcatId1 as $selected) {
            $insertskill=mysqli_query($db->connect(),"INSERT INTO skill(freelancer_id, subcat_id, project_id, employer_id)
                                                             value ('$freelancerid','$selected','','')");

        }


        if( $insertfree && $insertimgprofile && $insertimgbackground && $insertskill   )

        {

            $data = array("error"=>false,"MSG"=>"ثبت  با موفقیت انجام شد");
            echo json_encode($data);

            $db->endFile();
            return;
        }else{
            $data = array("error"=>true,"MSG"=>"خطای 1 پیش آمده");
            echo json_encode($data);
            $db->endFile();
            return;

        }





        }

}
session_destroy();

    ?>
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should use prepared statements.

Comment: `INSERT INTO .. VALUES` not `value`. Probably other errors also.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Comment: To get better detail about your problems, try to enable error reporting: add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any mysqli_ errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.